# Are there any events faster than DOMContentLoaded that can be set as the argument of addEventListener? what is that?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

Suppose that get a DOM as reference Node, then create and insert a DOM as new Node.

If I create and insert the new Node as soon as possible, is DOMContentLoaded the best event option in the above situation?

The reference Node is not image, it's HTMLnknowElement such as a HTMLDivElement, HTMLSpanElement.

Here is an example code flow.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
 // Below is an example code as pseudo code.

 // Get a reference DOM.
 const referenceEl = document.querySelector(".foo .reference-dom");
 // Create a new DOM.
 const newEl = document.createElement(htmlTag);
 // Insert the new DOM before reference DOM.
 referenceEl.parentElement.insertBefore(newEl, referenceEl.nextElementSibling)
})
```

If I execute the code as soon as possible, is DOMContentLoaded the best event option in the above situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the code to run as soon as possible, given what elements it depends on already existing in the DOM, the easiest way to do it would be to put your `<script>` tag just below the final element required for the script to run. For example, for the `.reference-dom`, you might do

```
<div class="reference-dom">
  ...
</div>
<script>
const referenceEl = document.querySelector(".foo .reference-dom");
// or
const referenceEl = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling;

// ... etc
```

If that's not an option, another avenue available to you would be to add a subtree [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to the document ahead of time (such as at the beginning of the `<body>`, and to watch the `addedNodes` to see if the node you're looking for appears - but that's expensive, overkill, and much more difficult to manage.

For very large pages ([example](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)), waiting for DOMContentLoaded could indeed take too long, in which case what you're doing *would* be a good idea - to add essential functionality to the app before that event fires, to ensure a good user experience. (Though, if what you're doing is just adding another tag to the HTML, a better approach would be to use a template engine or something server-side so that it serves the full HTML itself, rather than having to alter it client-side through JavaScript later)

Comment: Awesome...!!!

I didn't know these methods. I learned a lot... Thank you for teaching me.

In my situation, I think the subtree MutationObserver is the best option because maybe, It is a temporary code and will be removed in a few days.

Comment: Thank you for teaching. I did it.
I'm a beginner so I'm not used to this forum yet.